# How to debug a blocked Future.get() call?

Tags: java, concurrency, future

I have a code that waiting for the Future.get() method, it never returns. I generated a thread dump which indicates it is waiting for another thread <0x000000075e538dd0>. When I trying search for the thread with that thread id I couldn't find any record what does this tells me?

```
"Reader #9[worker][-1f2e83ef:1579b13caa9:-722e][AttributeJoinCollator]" #512 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000002254f800 nid=0x7374 waiting on condition     [0x00000000427ae000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x000000075e538dd0> (a         java.util.concurrent.FutureTask)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:429)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
at my.code.here(MyClass.java:416)
```

Comment: What kind of callback mechanism are you using that initiates the `get()` call?

Comment: We use org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.getThreadPoolExecutor.submit(Callable )